# Visual Studio 2015 keeps switching startup project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, project, startup

When changing startup project for the solution from project A (initial startup) to project B (newly added project) the change of the startup project does not appear to be saved.

When running F5 VS always change back to original setting of project A.

I have checked the settings and also options build and run (for new solutions use the currently selected project as startup project) is not checked.

I have tried to delete the .suo file and so far no luck so any other ideas whats going on ?

Comment: Does this occur just locally? If I'm not mistaken, the start project for a solution is not stored in the `*.sln` file, but in the `*.suo` file (which stores local settings and might be a hidden file).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Resharper , run configuration was the culprit in this case. The change was caused by that

Comment: Is there a bug report on this with JetBrains that I can contribute to?

Answer (score 75):

ReSharper -> Tools -> Run Configurations...

I like to delete all the run configurations I find in that menu.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks, I hate having so many stupid tools messing each other up.

Comment: Resharper is a great productivity tool, although sometimes I am disappointed by their ability to test or think things through.  I doubt there are any automated tests or serious UI planning sessions for anything more than surface deep going on at Jetbrains.  They have some real rock stars to work this way and have their tool work so well.

Comment: Thanks, thought I was going insane. I suspected ReSharper, but I had disabled it... thinking that would take it out of the picture.

Answer (score 10):

I had this experience after using the Resharper command 'Create Run Configuration' on a unit-test project. Thereafter, using F5 would always try (unsuccessfully) to run that project, and switch my default. I worked around it by running 'Create Run Configuration' again on the project I want to run.

I reported this as a bug at https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/853379?flash_digest=cf3e117b89155bb0dcffa49c21f732b49d461f49